# Better way to write some filters and post in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form working and am using strip_tags and htmlentities to try and prevent any malicious code or spam links being submitted by the contact form. Is there a better way to write, that is to combine the following:

```
$comments = $_POST['comments'] ;
$comments = strip_tags($comments);
$comments = htmlentities($comments);
```

I would like to figure out how to write that in one statement if possible. Also, when I have it in the order above, only strip_tags or htmlentities only the one listed first (in the above strip_tags) works.

A final question, is htmlentities or stripslahses better for preventing spammy links being sent in a contact form?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're saving that value in the database, remember to run `real_escape_string` on it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to figure out how to write that in one statement if possible

```
$comments = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['comments']));
```

Comment: Excellent, I had it backwards.